# Customizing table cells while using TWTRUserTimelineDataSource

Tags: ios, swift, twitterkit

I'm trying to load user timeline and customize cells, like replacing some text with emojis then display it. [The sample code](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/show-timelines) to load user timeline provided by twitter is like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let client = TWTRAPIClient()
    self.dataSource = TWTRUserTimelineDataSource(screenName: "someuser", 
                      apiClient: client)
}
```

But I could not find any detail about customizing `TWTRTweetTableViewCell` while using data source method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for `TWTRTimelineViewController` ([link](https://docs.fabric.io/appledocs/Twitter/Classes/TWTRTimelineViewController.html)):

> This class is a UITableViewController subclass that displays TWTRTweetTableViewCell cells.

That means you can override any `UITableView` delegate methods you wish.

For example, to set the background color of the cell to Orange:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let twCell = cell as? TWTRTweetTableViewCell {
        twCell.tweetView.backgroundColor = .orange
    }
}
```

It appears there are also "themes" you can configure. Just read through the docs... https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/appledocs/Classes/TWTRTweetView.html